# How can I redirect output files to a specific directory/folder

Tags: linux, command-line, io-redirection

Suppose I have an executable in Unix. Suppose the name of the .exe file is myExe and it takes two parameters. I did not create this executable, this is a freely available one.
myExe generates 4 different files. I want to direct all its output files to a specific folder. How can I do it in Unix command?
So I want something like this:

```
./myExe parameter1 parameter2  "output to /myfolder "
```

​So now the four files produced by myExe will be directed to myfolder. ​

Answer (score 3):

If `myExe` is in `./` and it defaults to writing to 4 files in `./` but you instead want those 4 files in `/myfolder` then you can do:

```
(cd /myfolder && "$OLDPWD/myExe" params)
```

...which will still write those 4 files to `./` but change the value of `./` to `/myfolder` for only the length of time it takes to for `./myExe` to write them.